# If iWork documents are XML based, yet iOS doesn't support XML persistance, how are the iWork for iPad apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, core-data, iwork

I am looking to create and iOS app that creates XML documents but was frustrated to see that Apple's persistence documentation states that "*The XML store is not available on iOS.*" However, Apple's iWork documents are XML based, and iWork is supported on iOS. How does that work?

Comment: Exactly what problem are you trying to solve? That this site can help with?

Answer (score 1):

Just because Apple doesn't include the XML store directly doesn't mean you can't read and write files in XML.  iOS includes support for [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and there are [many other parsers](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) available as well.

I don't know if iWork stores the files via Core Data or simply as files on disk via its Documents directory, but I'd lean towards the latter.  You could easily do the same - that is, add a method for serializing your document object into XML, writing it to disk, and then later read from disk and parse the XML back into the document object.